# Predictive modelling

Tags: machine-learning, regression

How to perform regression(Random Forest,Neural Networks) for this kind of data?

The data contains features and we need to predict sales qty based on week and attributes

[image: 1]

here I am attaching the sample data
[Here we are trying to predict sales quantity based on other attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7o65E.jpg)

Comment: Please share `dput(head(data.frame))`. There are many types of regression? Which one do you have in mind? You need to perform EDA first before jumping to regression.

Comment: Thank you @Tushar as per your request I uploaded sample data image

Answer (score 0):

Multivariate linear regression

Assuming

- input variables x[][] (each row corresponds to a sample, each column corresponds to a variable such as week, season, ..)
- expected output y[] (as many rows as x)
- parameters being learned theta[] (as many as there are input variables + 1)

you are optimizing a function h:

h = sum for all j of { x[j][i] * p[i] -  y[j] } is minimal

This can easily be achieved through gradient descent.
You can also include combinations of parameters (and simply include more thetas for those pseudo-parameters)

I have some code lying around in a GitHub repository that performs basic multivariate linear regression (for a course I sometimes teach).

https://github.com/jorisschellekens/ml/tree/master/linear_regression

Comment: Thank you @Joris
What I meant is there any suggestions for preparing the data and what kind of  data transformations we need to perform.We did things like encoded categorical variables and normalizing the data etc.

Comment: I added a link to code (since it would be too much for this particular post). If you approve of my answer, please mark it as the accepted answer (that way I get reputation points).

Comment: its not about how the linear regression is performed .We are trying to optimize the performance of our prediction task.last thing we are not trying any Linear regression we are trying by using Random forest and Neural Networks.Hope you get it

Comment: Then you should have said so in your question.
Regression refers to the broader technique of predicting a continuous variable from input, and can refer to a multitude of techniques, including random forests and linear regression.